# Whenever i scroll my page my background also scrolled how to fix this?

Tags: css

**This is my css codes**

```
.bg-main {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../img/mother.png) no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Comment: remove the `fixed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `fixed` from its styles.

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../img/mother.png) no-repeat center center !important; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover !important;
```